# How to generate PDB file for custom DNA squence(10 base pairs)

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing

I am trying to study docking of drug-DNA interaction and for that I need PDB file.

How can I get a pdb file for my custom dsDNA sequence (10-11 base pairs long)?

I will really appreciate if you can please guide me.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Pymol can build nucleic acids and is free for students.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Further to @canadianer here ins a link that looks as if it might be helpful https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Builder .

Answer (score 2):

[UCSF Chimera](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/) is free to use and is very versatile for molecular modeling. It has a `Build Structure` module (found in `Tools->Structure Editing`) useful for building proteins or nucleic acid sequences (selections in the left pane).

[image: Here I inserted the sequence]

Clicking `Apply` performs the build.

[image: 3D rendering]

It is then saved with `File->Save PDB`.
Note: the structure is devoid of hydrogen ions, which can be added using `Tools->Structure Editing->AddH`. I have always used this program because its outputs are readily accepted by [CHARMM-GUI](https://www.charmm-gui.org) (the server adds the hydrogen ions in this case).